# separate NHibernate.SQL empty file

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

I am trying to redirect NHibernate's sql to a separate file with the following configuration but with no success. Everything (with SQL queries) goes to the main file.
Can someone help?

```
 <log4net>
    <appender name="DebugSQL" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="nhsql.log"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern
          value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="Main" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="nh.log"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern
          value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugSQL" />
    </logger>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="Main" />
    </root>

  </log4net>
```

Comment: I just tested (exactly your setting) - it is working for me! no issues

Comment: It's because it was taken from some other StackOverflow post, so it should work. But it's strange that it doesn't work for me.

Comment: ;) now it makes sense... Well, maybe it could be like this: the file `nh.log` is filled, right? so NHibernate is in place. In my case, when I go on a list page, only one record appears in `nhsql.log` - the SELECT ***. Could you check (in profiler...) that there is really any SQL generated...

Comment: OK we have some progress. It appears that schema rebuild that I was running at the beggining is not logging to DebugSQL 

var schema = new SchemaExport(Config);
schema.Create(false, true);

but after Your suggestion I executed a query next, which was logged both to DebugSQL and Main. I can now add a filter to Main as Oskar Berggren suggested and it will work. I am not entirely happy with this solution, but I can live with it.

Comment: As you said: the config was working from the beginning, and we've just proven it;) Glad that it is now working for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That root configuration is going to send everything to the Main appender, in addition to sending the SQL to a separate file. If you want to prevent the SQL from showing up in the main log file, you need to search for "filter" in the log4net manual: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html Those should go inside the configuration for the main appender.

Comment: Adding the filter to main appender will only solve the part of the problem. I still can't get the sql to separate file.

Answer (score 2):

By default, loggers inherit all the appenders in their ancestors.  So the logger `NHibernate.SQL` will also log to all the appenders in the root looger.  You can prevent this with the `additivity` attribute:

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false" >
...
</logger>
```

Comment: This is exactly how I accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that only the initial SQL statments (creating table etc.) are not logged to separate file. Everything else is. So I guess that it has to be like that and this configuration is OK. Thanks everyone for help.